# What is the maximum addressable space of virtual memory?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, virtual, paging, memory-segmentation

Saw this questions asked many times. But couldn't find a reasonable answer. What is actually the limit of virtual memory?

Is it the maximum addressable size of CPU? For example if CPU is 32 bit the maximum is 4G?

Also some texts relates it to hard disk area. But I couldn't find it is a good explanation. Some says its the CPU generated address.

All the address we see are virtual address? For example the memory locations we see when debugging a program using GDB.

The historical reason behind the CPU generating virtual address? Some texts interchangeably use virtual address and logical address. How does it differ?

Comment: Calm down. Maybe reread and rewrite your question, but perhaps not before doing [some reading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) [of your own](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space).

Comment: I would write it out but it is a lot of typing....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer is "it depends". You didn't mention an operating system, but you implied linux when you mentioned GDB. I will try to be completely general in my answer.

There are basically three different "address spaces".

The first is logical address space. This is the range of a pointer. Modern (386 or better) have memory management units that allow an operating system to make your actual (physical) memory appear at arbitrary addresses. For a typical desktop machine, this is done in 4KB chunks. When a program accesses memory at some address, the CPU will lookup where what physical address corresponds to that logical address, and cache that in a TLB (translation lookaside buffer). This allows three things: first it allows an operating system to give each process as much address space as it likes (up to the entire range of a pointer - or beyond if there are APIs to allow programs to map/unmap sections of their address space). Second it allows it to isolate different programs entirely, by switching to a different memory mapping, making it impossible for one program to corrupt the memory of another program. Third, it provides developers with a debugging aid - random corrupt pointers may point to some address that hasn't been mapped at all, leading to "segmentation fault" or "invalid page fault" or whatever, terminology varies by OS.

The second address space is physical memory. It is simply your RAM - you have a finite quantity of RAM. There may also be hardware that has memory mapped I/O - devices that LOOK like RAM, but it's really some hardware device like a PCI card, or perhaps memory on a video card, etc.

The third type of address is virtual address space. If you have less physical memory (RAM) than the programs need, the operating system can simulate having more RAM by giving the program the illusion of having a large amount of RAM by only having a portion of that actually being RAM, and the rest being in a "swap file". For example, say your machine has 2MB of RAM. Say a program allocated 4MB. What would happen is the operating system would reserve 4MB of address space. The operating system will try to keep the most recently/frequently accessed pieces of that 4MB in actual RAM. Any sections that are not frequently/recently accessed are copied to the "swap file". Now if the program touches a part of that 4MB that isn't actually in memory, the CPU will generate a "page fault". THe operating system will find some physical memory that hasn't been accessed recently and "page in" that page. It might have to write the content of that memory page out to the page file before it can page in the data being accessed. THis is why it is called a swap file - typically, when it reads something in from the swap file, it probably has to write something out first, effectively swapping something in memory with something on disk.

Typical MMU (memory management unit) hardware keeps track of what addresses are accessed (i.e. read), and modified (i.e. written). Typical paging implementations will often leave the data on disk when it is paged in. This allows it to "discard" a page if it hasn't been modified, avoiding writing out the page when swapping. Typical operating systems will periodically scan the page tables and keep some kind of data structure that allows it to intelligently and quickly choose what piece of physical memory has not been modified, and over time builds up information about what parts of memory change often and what parts don't.

Typical operating systems will often gently page out pages that don't change often (gently because they don't want to generate too much disk I/O which would interfere with your actual work). This allows it to instantly discard a page when a swapping operation needs memory.

Typical operating systems will try to use all the "unused" memory space to "cache" (keep a copy of) pieces of files that are accessed. Memory is thousands of times faster than disk, so if something gets read often, having it in RAM is drastically faster. Typically, a virtual memory implementation will be coupled with this "disk cache" as a source of memory that can be quickly reclaimed for a swapping operation.

Writing an effective virtual memory manager is extremely difficult. It needs to dynamically adapt to changing needs.

Typical virtual memory implementations feel awfully slow. When a machine starts to use far more memory that it has RAM, overall performance gets really, really bad.